# How to stop buttons from overlapping when resizing window

Tags: html, css

I know there already are some questions about this, but none of them helped me fix the problem. (Also it is probably not a difficult solution but I am a beginner at html and css.)

So I am trying to design a small website and the problem ist, no matter what I do I can't seem to find a way to stop the elements on my website from overlapping as soon as I make the browser window smaller. Here are two screenshots of the problem:

[image]

[image]

And here is my code, first the CSS:

```
#Button1 {
        z-index: 1;
        left: 145px;
        top: 124px;
        height: 110px;
        width: 239px;
        left: 20%;
        top:20%;
        border-top-left-radius: 7px;
        border-top-right-radius: 7px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
        text-align: center;
        transition: all .2s ease;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 8px 5px;
        color: #000000; background-color: #F5F5F5; border: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
        cursor: pointer;
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 10px;
    }
    #Button1:Hover, #Button1:focus, #Button1:active { 
color: #fff;
background-color: #FFDB26;
border: 2px solid #BEC1CD;
}

 #Button2 {
        z-index: 1;
        left: 30px;
        top: 169px;
        margin-top: 0px;
        height: 130px;
        width: 260px;
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 10px;
    }
```

And here's the HTML I used:

```
<body>
<div style="z-index: 1; margin:20px; padding:30px; left: 0px; position: fixed; height: 100%; width: 44%; top: 15px;">
    <input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" /></div>
<div style="z-index: 1; padding: 30px; margin: 20px; left: 50%; position: fixed; height: 100%; width: 50%">
    <input id="Button2" type="button" value="button" /></div>
```

If someone could show me what to change in order for it to work, that'd be great.

Comment: An easy search. .. Try search before ask!

Comment: @Ingus 1. Bootstrap wasn't even used 2. No list is used in OP's code 3. Did you even check the answer in your link?

Comment: You're trying to make a 'responsive' web page. There's is indeed a huge amount of information on that out there. I would advice not to concentrate on just these two buttons, they are only a symptom of a problem which is solved by 'responsive web design'.

Comment: @CarlBinalla bootstrap or any other issue is the same

Comment: @Ingus as I stated in the question I **did** research. For 3 days, actiually, but nothing I tried fixed my problem.

Comment: [Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) should help you create responsive web pages.

Comment: @CarlBinalla Thank you, I'll take a look at media queries!

Comment: try tot add display:flex;

Comment: @Laura I see! I  added an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/xe42tzL9/

```
  <div class="but">
    <input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" />
    <input id="Button2" type="button" value="button" />
  </div>



.but {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  width:  100%;
}

#Button1 {

        left: 145px;
        top: 124px;
        height: 110px;
        width: 239px;
        left: 20%;
        top:20%;
        border-top-left-radius: 7px;
        border-top-right-radius: 7px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
        text-align: center;
        transition: all .2s ease;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 8px 5px;
        color: #000000; background-color: #F5F5F5; border: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
        cursor: pointer;
        margin: 10px;
    }
#Button1:Hover, #Button1:focus, #Button1:active { 
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #FFDB26;
        border: 2px solid #BEC1CD;
}

 #Button2 {

        left: 30px;
        top: 169px;
        margin-top: 0px;
        height: 130px;
        width: 260px;
        margin: 10px;
 }
```

Comment: Ahh I see how to do it. Thank you!